Why mockk library call verification fails for httpClient?
I get the error message in the below test case. Any ideas?
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 2 of 2: BlockingHttpClient(child of #1#3).retrieve(eq(POST /employee/create))) was not called

I have mocked httpClient.toBlocking() method, so why it was not called?
@KafkaListener(offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST, groupId = "test")
class EmployeeListener(@Client("\${demo.restapi}") val client: HttpClient) {
    var log = KotlinLogging.logger {}
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    @Topic("employee")
    fun recieveEmployee(str: String) {
        log.info { "Received employee creation request for $str" }

        try {
            val employeeDto  = gson.fromJson(str, EmployeeDto::class.java)

            val request: HttpRequest<Any> = HttpRequest.POST("/employee/create", employeeDto)
            val body = client.toBlocking().retrieve(request)
        } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
            log.error ("Error parsing json", e)
        }

        log.info("Employee creation request sent successfully")
    }
}

// test class
    val httpClient = mockk<HttpClient>(relaxed = true)

    val blockingHttpClient = mockk<BlockingHttpClient>(relaxed = true)

    test("Employee listener test") {
        val listener = EmployeeListener(httpClient)

        val request: HttpRequest<Any> = HttpRequest.POST("/employee/create", EmployeeDto("Test1"))

        every { httpClient.toBlocking() } returns blockingHttpClient
        every { blockingHttpClient.retrieve(any()) } returns "{'name': 'Test1'}"

        listener.recieveEmployee("{'name': 'Test1'}")

        verify { httpClient.toBlocking().retrieve(request) }
    }

UPDATE: Below code also doesnt work
@MicronautTest
class EmployeeListenerTest: FunSpec( {

    val httpClient = mockk<HttpClient>(relaxed = true)

    val blockingHttpClient = mockk<BlockingHttpClient>(relaxed = true)

    test("Employee listener test") {
        val listener = EmployeeListener(httpClient)

        val request: HttpRequest<Any> = HttpRequest.POST("/employee/create", EmployeeDto("Test1"))

        every { httpClient.toBlocking().retrieve(any()) } returns "{'name': 'Test1'}"
        //every { blockingHttpClient.retrieve(any()) } returns "{'name': 'Test1'}"

        listener.recieveEmployee("{'name': 'Test1'}")

        verify { httpClient.toBlocking().retrieve(any()) }
    }

})


Does it work if you replace request with any() in your verify block? I.e. verify { httpClient.toBlocking().retrieve(any()) }

no it doesnt work If I replace with any()

For some strange reason, the httpClient.toBlocking() inside your verify function does not return the same mocked instance of toBlocking() as outside of the verify call. So you're actually calling blockingHttpClient.retrieve but verifying that some other instance's retrieve was called. This can be demonstrated using the following minimal, self-contained reproducible example:
class MyTest : FreeSpec({
    class C {
        fun f() = "f"
    }

    class D {
        fun c() = C()
    }

    val c = mockk<C> { every { f() } returns "g" }
    val d = mockk<D> { every { c() } returns c }

    "test 1" {
        d.c().f()

        // Verification failed: call 2 of 2: C(child of #2#3).f()) was not called
        verify { d.c().f() }
    }

    "test 2" {
        d.c().f()

        // Verification succeeds
        verify { c.f() }
    }
})

Your issue can therefore be fixed by replacing your verify call with the following:
verify { blockingHttpClient.retrieve(request) }

Now, the question remains, why doesn't httpClient.toBlocking() return the same mock inside the verify as it does outside it? I don't know the answer to that, but I guess it's due to some limitation imposed by the implementation.
Another way to make your application work is to chain your mocks by changing your two mocks to the following line:
every { httpClient.toBlocking().retrieve(any()) } returns "{'name': 'Test1'}"

Then your original verify will work with the above.

Both of the solution you have suggested don't work. Strange issue
